# $\delta - \epsilon$ proof that $f(x) = x^2-2$ is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I've tried to proof that $f(x) = x^2-2$ is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ using the $\delta -\epsilon$ definiton of continuity, I think my proof is correct. But it's not the same as my textbook's. Would someone be willing to check whether this proof is correct?
 Here's my proof:
Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ be randomly given $f$ is continuous in $c$ if $\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \exists \delta \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ so that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ it is the case that $|x - c| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon$ such a $\delta$ exists, choose namely $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2\cdot|x+c|}$. This works, because $|f(x)-f(c)| = |(x^2-2)-(c^2-2)| = |x^2-c^2| = |(x-c)(x+c)| = |x-c| \cdot |x+c|$ But remember that $|x-c| < \frac{\epsilon}{2\cdot|x+c|}$, so $|x-c| \cdot |x+c| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2\cdot|x+c|} \cdot |x+c|= \frac{\epsilon}{2} <\epsilon$

So it is true that$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \exists \delta \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ $|x - c| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon$, and considering $c \in \mathbb{R}$ was randomly given, this stament holds $\forall c\in \mathbb{R}$, so f is continuous on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\delta$ cannot depend on x

Comment: oh of course, thanks!

Comment: @FoobazJohn why not? So long as it is not uniform continuity, aren't there are many proofs in which $\delta$ depends on x? $(\forall x)(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists \delta>0)(\forall y)(x,y \in \mathbb{R} \land |x-y|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon)$, meaing that $\delta$ can depend on x. With uniform continuity, we have that $(\forall \epsilon)(\exists \delta)(\forall x)(x,y \in \mathbb{R} \land |x-y|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon)$, which adds an additional constraint that $\delta$ can't depend on $x$.

Comment: nevermind, I just read this particular proof. I see what you mean. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you cannot have your $\delta$ depend on $x$. Instead, with these types of proofs, it's easier to start with what you *want*. delta-epsilon proofs tend to be easier for me when I start by working backward. We can get around the problem with your original proof with the following trick:

WlOG assume that $c>0$.

Goal: $|x^{2}-2-c^{2}+2|<\epsilon$

$|(x+c)(x-c)|<\epsilon$.

$|(x+c)|\cdot|x-c|<\epsilon$.

**Suppose that $\delta<1$.**

Then $|x-c|<1 \implies 2c-1<x+c<2c+1$

then $|x-c||x+c|<\epsilon \implies \delta\cdot(2c+1)<\epsilon $

...Can you see where this is headed? The idea is to get rid of the $x$ by only dealing with the entire $|x+c|$ term, instead of using $x$ explicitly. By assuming a *pretty* small delta (somewhat arbitrary), you can use this fact to get a neat expression for $\delta$. Notice my "WLOG", otherwise $|x+c|<2c+1$ isn't justified. Although you could very easily take the max of the two values.